# Knockout - style width not being set inside foreach

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have a viewmodel like this,

```
var sectorsViewModel = function() {
    this.sectors = ko.observableArray();
    this.maxValue = ko.observable();

    this.widthPercent = function(val, max) {
        return (val * 100) / max + '%';
    };
}
```

And this is the html,

```
<div data-bind="style : { width: widthPercent(10, 20) }"></div>
<!-- ko foreach: sectors -->
   <div data-bind="style : { width: $parent.widthPercent(sectorValue, $parent.maxValue()) }"
<!-- /ko -->
```

The width is being set correctly for the div outside the foreach loop. But the width is not being set for the div inside the foreach loop. If I put a breakpoint, I can see the widthPercent is being called for each sector, and the width value is being returned correctly by the function. Any idea why the width is not being set?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you forget to close that div?

Comment: looks working for me check the sample here http://jsfiddle.net/LkqTU/24932/ . @CrimsonChris pointed rightly so . issue is with `div` closing tag . cheers

Comment: I have the closing div in the actual code. I forgot to add it in the post.